# Open webpage, select all, copy into sheet

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Looking to copy Stock options data from Barcharts.com and paste into Excel sheet.

```
Sub CopyTables()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim I As Long
    I = 0
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.navigate "https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/GOOG/options?moneyness=allRows&view=sbs&expiration=2018-02-23"
    ie.Visible = True

    Do While ie.Busy And Not ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    DoEvents

  Set tables = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("table")
  SetDataFromWebTable tables, Range("B5")
  ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Also how would I extract the dates from the webpage dropdown "Expiration" and paste them all into Excel as well?

I have searched for something that will work for me, no luck!

Comment: ... and your **specific** question about your code is ...?

Comment: in addition to @Jeeped comment, where is the code for this procedure: `SetDataFromWebTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage source HTML by the link provided

https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/GOOG/options?moneyness=allRows&view=sbs&expiration=2018-02-23

doesn't contain the necessary data, it uses AJAX. The website https://www.barchart.com has an API available. Response is returned in JSON format. Navigate the page e. g. in Chrome, then open *Developer Tools* window (<kbd>F12</kbd>), *Network* tab, reload (<kbd>F5</kbd>) the page and examine logged XHRs. Most relevant data is JSON string returned by the URL:

https://core-api.barchart.com/v1/options/chain?symbol=GOOG&fields=optionType%2CstrikePrice%2ClastPrice%2CpercentChange%2CbidPrice%2CaskPrice%2Cvolume%2CopenInterest&groupBy=strikePrice&meta=field.shortName%2Cfield.description%2Cfield.type&raw=1&expirationDate=2018-02-23

[image: XHR-preview]

[image: XHR-headers]

You may use the below VBA code to retrieve info as described above. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test48759011()

    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    sUrl = "https://core-api.barchart.com/v1/options/chain?" & _
        Join(Array( _
            "symbol=GOOG", _
            "fields=" & _
            Join(Array( _
                "optionType", _
                "strikePrice", _
                "lastPrice", _
                "percentChange", _
                "bidPrice", _
                "askPrice", _
                "volume", _
                "openInterest"), _
            "%2C"), _
            "groupBy=", _
            "meta=" & _
            Join(Array( _
                "field.shortName", _
                "field.description", _
                "field.type"), _
            "%2C"), _
            "raw=1", _
            "expirationDate=2018-02-23"), _
        "&")
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .send
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    vJSON = vJSON("data")
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

The output for me is as follows:

[image: output]

To make output closer to Side-by-Side view on the webpage, you may slightly play with query parameters:

```vb
    sUrl = "https://core-api.barchart.com/v1/options/chain?" & _
        Join(Array( _
            "symbol=GOOG", _
            "fields=" & _
            Join(Array( _
                "optionType", _
                "strikePrice", _
                "lastPrice", _
                "percentChange", _
                "bidPrice", _
                "askPrice", _
                "volume", _
                "openInterest"), _
            "%2C"), _
            "groupBy=strikePrice", _
            "meta=", _
            "raw=0", _
            "expirationDate=2018-02-23"), _
        "&")
```

And also change the line

```vb
    Set vJSON = vJSON("data")
```

In that case the output is as follows:

[image: output2]

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).

Comment: It's a nice approach. Plus one for this.

Comment: Thank you so much @omegastripes ! that's incredible!

Comment: @omegastripes I've been struggling all morning to find a way within your provided script to set the Call & Puts columns side by side just like in the webpage https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/GOOG/options?moneyness=allRows&view=sbs&expiration=2018-02-23 . Would you be able to help with this? And I'll keep working on it, but how would I extract the expirations dates as well? Thanks to you I found the expirations available, but am no good at this type of code to extract them :(

Comment: @Stotch Try to modify query parameters within `sUrl` (that are shown on the screenshot also).Add `expirationDate` to `fields` parameter, similar to others.

Comment: @omegastripes oh wow that's good! I would've never been able to do that. My hat is off to you! Thank you!!!!!

Comment: @omegastripes And just figured out that changing "data" to "meta" scrapes the expiry dates! Thank you again! Hat is off, big time!

Comment: @omegastripes The URL has changed and I cannot seem to get the data with any modification I have tried. Would you be able to help with this please and thank you?! https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/GOOG/options